# azure savings plan utillization using python

Tags: python, azure, cost-management

I am using below trying to pull azure savings plan utilization data but I am getting error
AttributeError: 'CostManagementClient' object has no attribute 'benefit_utilization_summaries'

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
 from azure.mgmt.costmanagement import CostManagementClient
 from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
 from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    
      credential = ClientSecretCredential(
         tenant_id='',
         client_id= '',
         client_secret= ''
         )
            
         client = CostManagementClient(
             credential=credential
                
         )
            
         response = client.benefit_utilization_summaries.list_by_billing_account_id(
             billing_account_id="",
         )
         for item in response:
             print(item)
```

I am referring below azure documentation. can you guide me how what i am doing wrong and how can i fix it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/rest/api/cost-management/benefit-utilization-summaries/list-by-billing-account-id?tabs=Python#savingsplanutilizationsummaries-billingaccount

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support. If code **from the documentation** does not work, this is either a version incompatibility problem (make sure you understand which version of the library is described in your documentation, and how to determine the installed version) or a bug to be reported in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[azure-mgmt-costmanagement 3.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-costmanagement/#description) doesn't have the operation  benefit_utilization_summaries . This operation is recently added in the version [azure-mgmt-costmanagement 4.0.0b1](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-costmanagement/4.0.0b1/) which is currently in pre-release state.

You can update the package using below command

```
pip install azure-mgmt-costmanagement==4.0.0b1
```

Comment: any idea how can i put filter on this function at usage_date